# How to mount EC2 volume persistnantly as it losts files when I stop the instance in LINUX?

Tags: mount, amazon-ec2

I mounted volume by following it gets mounted but files get lost after stop.

mkfs -t ext2 /dev/sdb
mkdir /mnt/myVol
mount /dev/sdb /mnt/myVol

Answer (score 0):

If you want a volume whose data persists after you stop the EC2 instance that the volume is mounted on, you should use an [Elastic Block Store](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) volume.